# Why select2 not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I take the example from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeadr/62/).

I try in my localhost like this :

```
<select id="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#e1').select2({

    });
</script>
```

But it's not working

The result is like this :

[image]

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include `css` with `link` not with `script` as below:

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Also check for the dependency of `select2` versions with `jquery` versions..

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding... :) Do not forget to click on right mark beside the  Answer.. ;)

Comment: I need you help. look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209847/how-to-send-parameter-json-array-when-modal-open